# node position in tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I'd like to get the appended below commutative diagram by using tikz-cd. The source has been made in TeX, and the positioning of the nodes at the bottom row i.e. coker ker f and ker coker f have been obtained by the macro `\hidewidth`. But how can I get a similar result of `\hidewidth` in tikzcd?

The code in tikz-cd, without the alignment I'd like to get, is the following:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzcd}
    \ker f \arrow[r,"\varepsilon"] & A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d] & B\arrow[r,"\pi"] & \coker f \\
    & \coker\ker f\arrow[r,dotted,"\bar f"] & \ker\coker f\arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
```

Thank you!  [image]

Comment: Do you want the down arrow pointing exactly to `f` or should be centered with `Coker Ker f`?

Comment: I want coker ker f to be anchored on the right and ker coker f on the left, respectively

Comment: Have you made the diagram in `tikz-cd`, without the proper alignment of those nodes? If so, can you post the code?

Answer (score 3):

A variant based on `\mathllap` and `mathrlap` from `mathtools`; and a simple `\makebox`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{calc} 
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Coker}{Coker}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\Ker f \arrow[r] & A \arrow[r]\arrow[d] & B \arrow[r] & \Coker f \\
& \mathllap{\Coker \Ker{}} f \arrow[r] & \makebox[\widthof{$B$}][l]{$\mathrlap{\Ker\Coker f}$}\arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not a perfect solution, but it is starting point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\operatorname{Ker} f \arrow[r] & A \arrow[r]\arrow[d] & B \arrow[r] & \operatorname{Coker} f \\
& \llap{$\operatorname{Coker} \operatorname{Ker}{}$}f \arrow[r] & \mathrm{K} \rlap{$\operatorname{er}\operatorname{Coker} f $}\arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I'd prefer the top one. Anyway, this case can be solved by simply assign a fixed width to the long objects, here 1em, making them stick to the left and to the right respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\coker}{coker}

\begin{document}

\[% not center
\begin{tikzcd}
\ker f \arrow[r,"\varepsilon"] &
A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d] &
B\arrow[r,"\pi"] & \coker f
\\
&
\coker\ker f \arrow[r,dashed,"\bar f"] &
\ker\coker f \arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\[% not center
\begin{tikzcd}
\ker f \arrow[r,"\varepsilon"] &
A \arrow[r,"f"] \arrow[d] &
B\arrow[r,"\pi"] & \coker f
\\
&
\makebox[1em][r]{$\coker\ker f$} \arrow[r,dashed,"\bar f"] &
\makebox[1em][l]{$\ker\coker f$} \arrow[u]
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why not `center`? Because with `\[...\]` the display will not be separated by the text above it (no blank line before `\[`).

If you prefer “Ker” and “Coker” with the capital letter, use `\DeclareMathOperator` as shown for defining `\Ker` and `\Coker`.

Answer (score 2):

A pure `tikz-cd` solution, without hacking with `\makebox`, `\mathllap`, `\llap` or similar.

You can use the option:

```
/tikz/column 2/.append style={nodes={anchor=base east}}
```

to right align the nodes of the second column and:

```
/tikz/column 3/.append style={nodes={anchor=base west}}
```

to left align the nodes of the second column.

Then you can use the option `to path` to indicate the path you need, for example `to path={-- (\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget.north)}]` means "go to the point which has the x coordinate of the starting point and the y coordinate of the endpoint, north anchor.

For the arrow from the bottom left node to B, I used `<-` to invert the direction of the arrow in order to start it from B and being able to use `to path`.

I've also used `&[-5em]` to reduce the space between the first and the second column and between the third and the last.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[%
    /tikz/column 2/.append style={nodes={anchor=base east}},
    /tikz/column 3/.append style={nodes={anchor=base west}}
    ]
\operatorname{Ker} f \arrow[r] &[-5em] A \arrow[r]\arrow[d, start anchor=south,to path={-- (\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget.north)}] & B \arrow[r]\arrow[d, <-,to path={-- (\tikztostart |- \tikztotarget.north)}] &[-5em] \operatorname{Coker} f \\
& \operatorname{Coker} \operatorname{Ker} f \arrow[r] & \operatorname{Ker} \operatorname{Coker} f 
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]